# How to convert last insert id into string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, html

I have a create account page and on the page I have one button to insert all the details into two seperate tables one of the tables Pictures is dependant on the User table 1:1 relationship via UserID.

I have written some code to try get the last insert id so I can insert into the pictures table:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=root; Password=commando;");
cn.Open();

                OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO User (Email, FirstName, SecondName, DOB, Location, Aboutme, username, password) VALUES ('" + TextBox1.Text + "', '" + TextBox2.Text + "', '" + TextBox3.Text + "', '" + TextBox4.Text + "', '" + TextBox5.Text + "', '" + TextBox6.Text + "', '" + TextBox7.Text + "', '" + TextBox8.Text + "')", cn);
                OdbcCommand sc = new OdbcCommand("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()", cn);
                //convert LAST INSERT into string theUserId

                string filenameDB = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
                string fileuploadpath = Server.MapPath("~/userdata/" + theUserId + "/uploadedimage/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileuploadpath);
                string fileuploadpaths = ("~/userdata/" + theUserId + "/uploadedimage/") + filenameDB;
                Label10.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
                OdbcCommand cm = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO Pictures (picturepath, UserId) VALUES ('" + fileuploadpaths + "', " + theUserId + ")", cn);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label10.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;

            }
            //e.Authenticated = true;
            //Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
            // Event useradded is true forward to login
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure if this is correct and I also need to know how to convert the select statement into a string so I can retrieve the UserID from the User table, see database structure:

[image]

**EDIT**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=root; Password=commando;");


            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO User (Email, FirstName, SecondName, DOB, Location, Aboutme, username, password) VALUES ('" + TextBox1.Text + "', '" + TextBox2.Text + "', '" + TextBox3.Text + "', '" + TextBox4.Text + "', '" + TextBox5.Text + "', '" + TextBox6.Text + "', '" + TextBox7.Text + "', '" + TextBox8.Text + "')SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()", cn);
            //OdbcCommand sc = new OdbcCommand("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()", cn);
            //convert LAST INSERT into string theUserId
            //using (DataTable dt = DataTier.ExecuteQuery(cmd))
            ////error for datatable and datatier
            //if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
            //{
            //    //Read the new ID from the record that has just been inserted
            //    string theUserId = dt.Rows[0]["UserID"].ToString();
            using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
           
            string theUserId = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(0));

            string filenameDB = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
            string fileuploadpath = Server.MapPath("~/userdata/" + theUserId + "/uploadedimage/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileuploadpath);
            string fileuploadpaths = ("~/userdata/" + theUserId + "/uploadedimage/") + filenameDB;
            Label10.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
            OdbcCommand cm = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO Pictures (picturepath, UserId) VALUES ('" + fileuploadpaths + "', " + theUserId + ")", cn);
            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label10.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;

        }
        //e.Authenticated = true;
        //Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        // Event useradded is true forward to login
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query similar to the following to post a record, then get the ID.

```
 string sQuery = @"INSERT INTO [ExpenseType]
                                      (
                                         [ExpenseTypeName]
                                        ,[Deleted]
                                        ,[IsTaxable]
                                        ,[UpdatedDate]
                                        ,[UpdatedUser]
                                        ,[ParentCategoryComponentID]
                                        ,[CategoryComponentID]
                                        ,[NLNominalAccountID]
                                        ,[SYSTaxCodeID]
                                      )
                                      VALUES
                                      (
                                         @ExpenseTypeName
                                        ,@Deleted
                                        ,@IsTaxable
                                        ,@UpdatedDate
                                        ,@UpdatedUser
                                        ,@ParentCategoryComponentID
                                        ,@CategoryComponentID
                                        ,@NLNominalAccountID
                                        ,@SYSTaxCodeID
                                      )
                                      SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS 'ID' ";

                    using ( SqlCommand oSqlCommand = new SqlCommand( sQuery ) )
                    {
                        oSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@ExpenseTypeName", this.ExpenseTypeName );
                        oSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@Deleted", this.Deleted );
                        oSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@IsTaxable", this.IsTaxable );
                        oSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@UpdatedDate", base.GetUpdatedDate() );
                        oSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@UpdatedUser", base.GetUpdatedUser() );
                        oSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@ParentCategoryComponentID", this.ParentCategoryComponentID );
                        oSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@CategoryComponentID", this.CategoryComponentID );
                        oSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@NLNominalAccountID", this.NLNominalAccountID );
                        oSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@SYSTaxCodeID", this.SYSTaxCodeID );

                        using ( DataTable dt = DataTier.ExecuteQuery( oSqlCommand ) )
                        {
                            if ( dt.Rows.Count == 1 )
                            {
                                //Read the new ID from the record that has just been inserted
                                                                string RecordID =  dt.Rows[ 0 ][ "ID" ].ToString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Note the SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS 'ID' at the end of the query.

and

```
          if ( dt.Rows.Count == 1 )
                        {
                            //Read the new ID from the record that has just been inserted
                            string RecordID =  dt.Rows[ 0 ][ "ID" ].ToString();
                        }
```

Comment: does SCOPE_IDENTITY work the same way as Select last_insert_id?

Comment: i need the last inserted userid so I can pass that to the insert into pictures

Comment: SCOPE_IDENTITY() Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch. Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch. I have not heard of Select Last Insert ID before. is it your method?

Comment: ok, first insert your user record in a single query, store the UserID returned from the query and use this when firing your next query to insert the picture record

Comment: SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() is mysql syntax

Comment: just googled it and found out a bit about it - this SO post is worth a read, it may be better to use SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Comment: ah no, sorry it was tagged SQL and my SQL :p

Comment: yup sorry lol ive redited my post I get an error on datatable and datatier for your using method

Comment: yeah sorry, you have the right aproach anyway, you just need to read the last inserted ID from the user table after you have inserted the record. Just make sure you are gettin the ID for the scope of the user table and not the last ID inserted into the database. Im not sure if there is a scope_identity equivalent in ODBC but google may have the answer to that particular question :)